# Used purge command to remove java, it removed a lot more than java

Tags: 12.04, command-line, package-management, 64-bit, java

I used this purge command `sudo apt-get purge openjdk7*`, however this uninstalled a lot of the software and my me menu has vanished. Every time I install something there is a huge list of packages the system wants me to remove by using the command `sudo apt-get autoremove`. I looked trough these, and some were recently installed, but are recognized as orphaned packages.

Is there any way I can solve this, or do I have to format and install Ubuntu again? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64.

Here are pastebins of three relevant log files from my system:

[`/var/log/dpkg.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1013394/)

[`/var/log/apt/history.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1013398/)

[`/var/log/apt/term.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1013400/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from the APT history log, the problem wasn't `apt-get purge openJDK7*`, which uninstalled openjdk, but `apt-get purge java*` which removed `ubuntu-desktop`.

The problem is that `java*` matches `javascript` :)

To get back to a usable system, `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

To get everything you had installed back, install everything you can see that APT removed when you told it to purge `java*`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out :) I was sure that i used `sudo apt-get purge opendJDK7` when it went wrong. I went trough the list, and I don't know how, but most of the ones that were removed showed as installed and latest version. I wish I could give you vote up, but I am not allowed. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you or not, but I had no issues using the purge command to get rid of openjdk. I did this of course to install the official oracle-java7. Here are the steps I took:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Hope this helps, sorry if it doesn't!

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I wanted to uninstall openjdk, and install oracle-java7. I have oracle-java installed. When i used the purge command, it uninstalled a lot more than just java. it purged, if I remember correctly 144 MB, that is a lot more than just java. It even uninstalled software center. But that is ok, since I managed to install it again. The me-menu dissapeared also. I checked to see if it were still installed, and it shows as installed, but it doesn't show on the panel. I have no idea, what the purge command uninstalled. But thanks for trying to help :)